# How to access locators which are stored in some other file in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jasmine

I have a file called locators which stores all my variables and elements. However I need to prepare different spec files for different cases and I am unable to access the variables stored in my locator file.
I am using the following code in my spec file -

```
var loc = require("../locators.js");
```

However whenever I am using a function on the variable from the var file it gives the following error - 
`Cannot read property 'sendKeys' of undefined` (as here I am using sendKeys)

The variable in locator file is declared as -

```
var userName = element(by.model("someModelName"));
```

It is being called as

```
loc.userName.sendKeys("ABC");
```

What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: `userName` is a variable, not a property of `loc`.  You need to either make userName a property of `loc` i.e. `this.userName = ...` or do prototypal inheritance

Comment: Thanks a ton !! 
It is working for me now !

Comment: @Gunderson It's working fine for me too..but when I print loc.userName , instead of printing just the "someModelName" , it is printing ElementArrayFinder, config.js and many  other logs...can you pls let me know where am I doing wrong here ?